# How to remove an event listener from window?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, events, listener

Im building a snake game and need to remove an event listener after the space bar has fired, but im not getting any luck as the following code;

```
window.removeEventListener('keypress', (event)
```

doesn't do anything. Any ideas what is the proper way for this? Thanks

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  console.log(event)
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    startGame()
    window.removeEventListener('keypress', (event))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reference to the function in order to remove it. Don't use anonymous functions, instead:

```
function handleKeyPress(event){
  console.log(event)
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    startGame()
    window.removeEventListener('keypress', (event))
  }
})

//add it
window.addEventListener('keypress',handleKeyPress);
//remove it
window.removeEventListener('keypress',handleKeyPress);
```

Comment: Changed this `window.removeEventListener('keypress', (event))` to this `window.removeEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress)` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you will remove your event listener, you must define it as a function with a name, rather than an inline function as you have done. Then give its name when you add, and when you remove, it.

That's because an element may have multiple listeners for the same event. When you remove one, you must specify which one.